# Error: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1" when running code on a new machine

Tags: flutter, flutter-linux

I have a project that compiles and runs successfully on my development machine. However, when I try to run it on a new machine

> flutter run -d linux

I encounter the following error:

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`

when I create a new project on the new machine (flutter create test_project), it builds and runs without any issues. Then i move my code in lib to test_project (and also added pubspec, manifest ...). Again the above error comes up wit saying "build process failed"

Here are some details about the environment:

Original Machine: ubuntu 23 (latest)

New Machine: ubuntu 22.04

Comment: i believe you have audioplayers package in your pubspec.yaml right

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as you, solved it doing the following:

- ran the app using `flutter run -v` (this shows exactly the missing library or the exact error clang is detecting when running)
- install the missing lib (in my case, it was `lmediainfo`, i searched on google for libmediainfo-dev and installed
- rerun and everything worked just fine!